# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, hdfs, nltk

I have just begin to learn spark and trying to do some text analysis using spark/nltk and python on a Windows Environment, Attached Is my Code and the complete error message, please have a look at it and help me

I have set of reviews in tsv files that i loaded into hdfs and then print the comments and it works fine, only print works when i try to load them into graph it gives error

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit
from functools import reduce
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import pandas as pd
import re
import string

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('AmazonAlexaUserReview').master('local').getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("rating", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("date", StringType(), True),
    StructField("variation", StringType(), True),
    StructField("verified_reviews", StringType(), True),
    StructField("feedback", IntegerType(), True)])
data_DF = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("delimiter","\t").schema(schema).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").option("inferSchema", "True").csv('amazon_alexa.tsv')
data_DF.createOrReplaceTempView("data")

reviews_rdd = data_DF.select("verified_reviews").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
# print(reviews_rdd.collect())
header = reviews_rdd.first()
data_rmv_col = reviews_rdd.filter(lambda row: row != header)

lowerCase_sentRDD = data_rmv_col.map(lambda x : x.lower())



def sent_TokenizeFunct(x):
    return nltk.sent_tokenize(x)
sentenceTokenizeRDD = lowerCase_sentRDD.map(sent_TokenizeFunct)


def word_TokenizeFunct(x):
    splitted = [word for line in x for word in line.split()]
    return splitted
wordTokenizeRDD = sentenceTokenizeRDD.map(word_TokenizeFunct)


def removeStopWordsFunct(x):
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stop_words=set(stopwords.words('english'))
    filteredSentence = [w for w in x if not w in stop_words]
    return filteredSentence

stopwordRDD = wordTokenizeRDD.map(removeStopWordsFunct)

def removePunctuationsFunct(x):
    list_punct=list(string.punctuation)
    filtered = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in list_punct) for s in x]
    filtered_space = [s for s in filtered if s] #remove empty space
    return filtered
rmvPunctRDD = stopwordRDD.map(removePunctuationsFunct)


def lemmatizationFunct(x):
    nltk.download('wordnet')
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    finalLem = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(s) for s in x]
    return finalLem
lem_wordsRDD = rmvPunctRDD.map(lemmatizationFunct)


def joinTokensFunct(x):
    joinedTokens_list = []
    x = " ".join(x)
    return x
joinedTokens = lem_wordsRDD.map(joinTokensFunct)






def extractPhraseFunct(x):
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

    def leaves(tree):
        """Finds NP (nounphrase) leaf nodes of a chunk tree."""
        for subtree in tree.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'NP'):
            yield subtree.leaves()

    def get_terms(tree):
        for leaf in leaves(tree):
            term = [w for w, t in leaf if not w in stop_words]
            yield term

    sentence_re = r'(?:(?:[A-Z])(?:.[A-Z])+.?)|(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*)|(?:\$?\d+(?:.\d+)?%?)|(?:...|)(?:[][.,;"\'?():-_`])'
    grammar = r"""
        NBAR:
            {<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}  # Nouns and Adjectives, terminated with Nouns

        NP:
            {<NBAR>}
            {<NBAR><IN><NBAR>}  # Above, connected with in/of/etc...
        """
    chunker = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    tokens = nltk.regexp_tokenize(x, sentence_re)
    postoks = nltk.tag.pos_tag(tokens)  # Part of speech tagging
    tree = chunker.parse(postoks)  # chunking
    terms = get_terms(tree)
    temp_phrases = []
    for term in terms:
        if len(term):
            temp_phrases.append(' '.join(term))

        finalPhrase = [w for w in temp_phrases if w]  # remove empty lists
        return finalPhrase
extractphraseRDD = joinedTokens.map(extractPhraseFunct)


def sentimentWordsFunct(x):
    from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
    analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    senti_list_temp = []
    for i in x:
        y = ''.join(i)
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(y)
        senti_list_temp.append((y, vs))
        senti_list_temp = [w for w in senti_list_temp if w]
    sentiment_list = []
    for j in senti_list_temp:
        first = j[0]
        second = j[1]

        for (k, v) in second.items():
            if k == 'compound':
                if v < 0.0:
                    sentiment_list.append((first, "Negative"))
                elif v == 0.0:
                    sentiment_list.append((first, "Neutral"))
                else:
                    sentiment_list.append((first, "Positive"))
    return sentiment_list


sentimentRDD = extractphraseRDD.map(sentimentWordsFunct)


freqDistRDD = extractphraseRDD.flatMap(lambda x : nltk.FreqDist(x).most_common()).map(lambda x: x).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x+y).sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending = False)



df_fDist = freqDistRDD.toDF() #converting RDD to spark dataframe
df_fDist.createOrReplaceTempView("myTable")
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT _1 AS Keywords, _2 as Frequency from myTable limit 20") #renaming columns
pandD = df2.toPandas() #converting spark dataframes to pandas dataframes
pandD.plot.barh(x='Keywords', y='Frequency', rot=1, figsize=(10,8))



wordcloudConvertDF = pandD.set_index('Keywords').T.to_dict('records')
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=500, random_state=21, max_font_size=100, relative_scaling=0.5, colormap='Dark2').generate_from_frequencies(dict(*wordcloudConvertDF))
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 10))
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The Complete Error Message I get :

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]19/05/07 14:25:27 ERROR PythonRunner: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)
19/05/07 14:25:27 ERROR PythonRunner: This may have been caused by a prior exception:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)
19/05/07 14:25:27 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)
19/05/07 14:25:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)

19/05/07 14:25:28 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/SearchForBussiness/MonDemo.py", line 28, in <module>
    header = reviews_rdd.first()
  File "E:\SearchForBussiness\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1378, in first
    rs = self.take(1)
  File "E:\SearchForBussiness\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1360, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
  File "E:\SearchForBussiness\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 1069, in runJob
    sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
  File "E:\SearchForBussiness\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "E:\SearchForBussiness\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "E:\SearchForBussiness\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you resolve it ?